# Symfony 2: The Web server doesn't rewrite the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

when I put my web app (Symfony2) on production for this time the server doesn't rewrite (it often does) the URL and I don't know why. I usualuse the .htaccess files in the root and in the web folder.

.htaccess in root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

.htaccess in /web:

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]

the following error is generated by the server:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@subdomaine_goes_here.domaine_goes_here.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: I use a subdomaine you can access it on : http://iballot.yameinstitute.com/

Comment: Can you share your Virtual Host settings for subdoman. May you need change apache settings AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

successfully solve the problem by putting two .htaccess files in the projects folders (REMEMBER: I'm using a sub-domain):

in root /:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]

in /web folder: I keept the original .htaccess file ships with symfony 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You don't need .htaccess in root, you need .htaccess in your web directory and and domain should be set to point the web directory. Of course it can be customised but it's the best solution (php files are not accessible from browser). .htaccess should point web/app.php on production

Whole server configuration part can be found on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: when I remove the .htaccess from the root, the server look like it does not index the web folder: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: because there is no index.php file in symfony it needs to be pointed on app.php instead whole configuration is at the link I gave you in the answer

Comment: Change your `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` sort as it point to the `web` directory (e.g. `public_html/web`) . The good .htaccess will be used and will automatically take the `app.php` as `DirectoryIndex`.

Comment: I don't think it can work because when I go to http://iballot.yameinstitute.com/web/ I still get the same error (clik on the link to see the error)

Comment: you have still wrong directory pointed on your domain check virutal host settings. If you go to http://iballot.yameinstitute.com/web/app.php it works. So host configruation is wrong